# Need more comment flags!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, flags, comment-voting

Hey, cool, the 10K tools list comment flags now! **It's time to cleanse the city, Davey!**

Wait, only 5 flags still? Ouch. That doesn't go very far.

How 'bout... 300. Or at least 40. They burn off quick...

Comment: Seems a little silly that (at the moment) nearly all the flagged comments either ask about or refer to a downvote, and not even in a rude way. Is that really a flag-worthy offense? I think maybe some people are using comment *flags* as comment *downvotes*.

Comment: @gno: no, I just really, really detest "why the downvotes" comments, and wish they would all go away. It's noise, pure and simple: there's no notification for the down-voter(s), so at best you'll get someone trying to explain on their behalf, and at worst... Sympathy votes.

Comment: Is it just me or is this page really hard to read now? Where's the count of spam vs. offensive flags on each post? And it's hard to tell the difference between up/downvote counts and flag counts.

Comment: @Ether: Exactly what I thought. I think a post will get listed if it has either flags on *it*, or flags on *its comments*, in which case the comments are also listed. I think part of the confusion may be that there just aren't any posts with flags at the moment, hard as that may be to imagine.

Comment: @Shog: You make a good point. **Okaaaaaaay Daaaaaavey.**

Comment: @Ether: yeah, it took me a little while to figure out what was going on. One column for everything and no labels... *sigh*

Comment: @Ether: Looks like a post flag just showed up. They are apparently in red, while comment flags are in blue. Still kinda hard to follow though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flagging *appropriately* is a positive and constructive thing for the network. We've recently made a change that allows users with high rep (showing general site knowledge) or high flag-weight (showing previous history of helpful flagging) additional moderator (etc) flags.

Going forwards, this change will also apply to comment flags, so you should be well armed to clean up the town.

Happy flagging.

Comment: Excellent! Now to watch my flag-weight plummet...

Comment: Is at least a rough algorithm for the number availible somewhere? I always wondered why the "inform moderator flags remaining" changes all the time.

Comment: @tohecz k; 10 votes per day default, plus one extra per 2000 reputation, plus an extra bit based on a very-hard-to-describe measure of your previous flagging success, up to a maximum of 100. Basically, you can get extra flags by either having high reputation (so lots of site experience), or by having a good track record of flagging.

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend we gradually increase the allotted number of flags.  We could even do it based on a user's "score" of the valid/invalid comment flags they've thrown in the past.  There's definitely a different threshold for what's allowed in comments vs. what's allowed in answers and questions.

Comment: Shoot!  I was going to put a "Needs more cow bell!" joke in here and I forgot.

Comment: I got a fever, Bill, and the only prescription is **more flags**!