# Question comments unrelated to an answer or to OP

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface

I looked around and could not find anyone asking this question, but it seems like something that I would think a lot of people would ask. So either I'm not navigating this site (in which case, a link to the discussion about this would be wonderful) or I am the only one?

Anyway, while browsing questions, or looking at questions I have asked, or questions I have answered, I sometimes feel like there should be a little sort of comment-like box, just like the comments under every answer and every question, but that are not specific.

What I mean is, let's say there is a question which has three answers, none of which have been accepted by the OP. And I would like to know which of them is actually "the answer" now. I feel that asking it under the OP question is wrong, and obviously asking it under any particular question is wrong, shouldn't there be a generic "comments" section for all questions, that aren't specific to the OP code or question, or any answer.

Often times the comments under the OP question can get very long and many unrelated or separate discussions are going on at once, and answer comments are never predictable.

There are many examples I could give, but I don't want to create a wall of text. I'm sure you can understand, my point and I would really like to know what people think about this. Or maybe there is already some sort of solution or acceptable method to my dilemma?

edit: in short I think there should be a feature which is a comment box just like under questions and answers that is not related to a question or an answer, that exists in each question.

Comment: There is a question somewhere there trying to get out. Can you help us out and spell out your "dilemma"?

Comment: @Oded im pretty sure i asked it, but il make it more clear in the post.

Comment: Sorry, all I can see is a rambling story about comments to all answers and such, but no real question or suggestion as such.

Comment: @Oded its the second paragraph, but i edited at the end with a summary.

Comment: And? What do you expect the function and effect of such a comment box to be?

Comment: @Oded general questions or comments about the question and all the answers, not a question or comment specific to a question or am answer... im pretty sure i was clear on that.

Comment: I understand you want a general comment box, but what good would it be? Running commentary? My point being that you are suggesting a feature, but no compelling reason for having it.

Comment: @Oded well, for starters, the example i gave, where if someone comes to the site and looks up a question and sees 3 possible answers where none are selected and is not sure which is the one he wants, he can ask. (even though this is probably a rare occurance) and a second example would be if the OP asks a question about some code, so obviously the OP does not know the answer, and sometimes, doesnt even know anything about the code or any code at all, in this case, comments on the OP post about the code seem somewhat out of place since you arent really asking the OP what he was doing...

Comment: ... or for clarification but instead are asking other users or SO what they think about certain code attributes, or how a specific task should be handled. these questions are not directed at the OP or his post, they are about the answers, but not any specific answer...

Comment: The question is: who do you want to answer to a comment? If it's the OP, comment the question. If it's an answerer, comment the answer, maybe more answers. If it's nobody... well that's the reason that there is no general comment box.

Comment: @InbarRose-I don't think the general comment box would be a good addition. It will likely turn into a FB wall where all things anything will be discussed and argued about to no end. Shouldn't the person looking up that question be able to reduce their options down and test the ones they feel might be good for their solution?

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you mean - kind of a "Question Wall" or question "Shout Box" allowing general comments in the question page.

The closest thing that was already asked is:
[Separate clarifying comment questions to the original post from non-clarifying comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116185/separate-clarifying-comment-questions-to-the-original-post-from-non-clarifying-c)

Which is pretty much buried by the community.

Personally I can't see any value in such feature. If the comment is about the question itself, ask it under the question. If the comment is about one of the answers, ask it under that answer. In any "general" case like the one you gave (*let's say there is a question which has three answers, none of which have been accepted by the OP. And I would like to know which of them is actually "the answer" now*) the proper place is under the question then the OP can tell why he/she didn't accept any of the answers and other users can also comment back telling which answer they think is the best.

At some cases this Meta site is the place to discuss questions on Stack Overflow for example when user want to know why his question got closed or deleted.

Comment: you conciseness pleases me. i am jealous, but i also understand your point. however, i would still like to ask, is there any reason not to have this?

Comment: @Inbar don't be jealous.. just enough experience in forums followed by lots of time here. Anyway no, no real or official reason not to have such thing like I said this is my personal feeling. Usually the amount of votes on the suggestion tells the general "support level" of the community but the developers have their own schedule.

Comment: copied from the link you mentioned in your answer: originally posted by @Pekka "There are some conceivable slight variations of the idea - e.g., a "shoutbox" whose contents will be purged after 24 hours, underneath the regular comments. Or "temporary" comments that are specially marked (like with an hourglass or something) and removed after 24 hours." this is pretty much exactly what i was thinking.

Comment: In such case you can gain some reputation here then place a bounty on that other question asking for authorative reference - that request is still pending after all.

Comment: @InbarRose Not that I'm against new ideas, but I wonder if a temporary comment box will work. I think the majority of users only visits SO once in a few days or weeks. Even after "dropping" a question they often seem to be gone right away.

Comment: @GertArnold but why temporary comment box will help in such case of users visiting, asking and going away?

Comment: No, it won't is what I tried to say. I probably should have said "I doubt" not "I wonder"