# Has there been a change to the number of spam/offensive flags?

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-weight

I just noticed that I had almost as many spam/offensive flags as moderator flags, which I'm quite sure wasn't the case earlier today.

Is this also dependant on the flag weight now?

[image: Screenshot of flag dialog]

Comment: If this is true, I wholly support and applaud the change (I seem to have 34 now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there has been a change as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81576/how-can-we-improve-commenting-on-the-stack-exchange-network/81649#81649) by Marc. They're based on reputation/weight.

Comment: Though that comment doesn't explicitly mention the spam/offensive flags, unless that's counted as part of the etc, so I'm still not completely certain that he wasn't just talking about that previous flag weight changes that did not affect these flags.

Comment: @ho1, I took it as being included in the etc. Could be wrong though...

Comment: You are correct, Brandon. We also got [more comment flags!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74546/need-more-comment-flags)